# ¿Qué significa “D.A.R.” en los créditos de este álbum?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, música, siglas

Estoy buscando datos de unas canciones que tengo en mi colección. [Este CD](https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-615620816-los-llayras-corazon-adolorido-cd-1995-ediciones-fracor-_JM) tiene versiones de unas de estas canciones, pero algunas tienen solamente “D.A.R.” como compositor:

[image: Corazón adolorido]

Dada la naturaleza de estas canciones, creo que “D.A.R.” significa algo similar a “tradicional” o “de origen desconocido”, pero no puedo pensar en tres palabras con esta acepción que formen la abreviatura correcta.

Comment: Así aparece también en otro de sus discos: [Grandex Éxitos](https://www.allmusic.com/album/grandes-exitos-mw0002044488). Parece que fuera _Derecho de Autor Reservado_, es decir, un _cover_ de una canción de otro autor.

Comment: Probablemente son canciones de autor desconocido. _Derechos a reclamar_, dice alguien en Yahoo Answers (esta página no es muy buena fuente). O sea, la canción no tiene derechos reservados todavía, aunque alguien podría reclamarlos.

Comment: What? Peter Schilling?? Are you [Major Tom's Peter Schilling](https://www.peterschilling.com) ?? it would be fun... the author of Major Tom asking about Mexican popular music. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por una vez y sin que sirva de precedente, voy a citar [una respuesta](https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100312161844AAr8E0j) de Yahoo! Respuestas:

> Eso significa DERECHO de AUTOR RESERVADO, y se usa cuando el autor de la canción NO QUIERE que sea revelado su nombre, o cuando quienes ponen el crédito NO SABEN EL NOMBRE DEL AUTOR y para no quemarse y que les cobren multas en DERECHOS DE AUTOR poniendo otro nombre, ponen D. A. R.

Me parece bastante creíble, y tiene más sentido que lo de audio digital teniendo en cuenta que lo ponen en donde normalmente se indica el autor (es cierto que en los CD se especificaba si la grabación era digital o analógica pero no se ponía ahí, que yo recuerde).

Comment: También es, o era hace unos años, habitual poner *D. R* en estos casos, por *Derechos Reservados*. En efecto, es una forma de reconocer los derechos de quien los tenga, cuando no se sabe quién es. Esto ocurre muchas veces en música folclórica, como la del disco de la pregunta. En España lo he visto en discos de flamenco.